# How to quit after run IO.read(:stdio, :all) in the Elixir iex?

Tags: io, elixir, eof, elixir-iex

I need test some input  data flow, and use 'IO.read', but after entering data i can't exit from this mode, CTRL-Z/X/C/D doesn't help (it terminates the whole iex). So how correct EOF command for this mode?
Thanks!

Comment: For any IO read operation, the correct EOF termination would be `^D`.

Comment: Apparently, it does not work in `iex` session for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR:* Use `^G` followed by `j`, `i [nn]` and `c [nn]`.

---

In both `erl` and `iex` shells you always might `^G` to enter a “User switch command” mode. Type `h` for help there.

```
iex|1 ▶ IO.read :stdio, :all

^G
User switch command
  --> j
    1* {erlang,apply,[#Fun<Elixir.IEx.CLI.1.96155272>,[]]}
  --> i 1
  --> c 1
{:error, :interrupted}

iex|2 ▶
```

---

*Sidenote:* the correct `EOF` termination would be `^D` in all the terminals. I honestly have no idea why it does not work as expected in `erl`/`iex` consoles.

Comment: Strangely this doesn't seem to be working for me on MacOS 10.13. After `c 1` it doesn't return a value, it just goes into the same state as it was before pressing `^G`.

Comment: @Dogbert oh, thanks for the sharp eye; I copy-pasted one of my experiments, not the last succeeded one. One should interrupt the job before switching to it. Updated.

Comment: Since all the input sank into your `IO.read`, it’s a responsibility of your code to somehow make this data available. One might use ETS, or `Agent`, or like for that.